# Correct way of importing data from json in Ionic 2 using an interface

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I'm really wondering what's the correct and best-practice way for importing data from a json file in an ionic 2 project so I can show it in a template, for example. 
Some solutions I can find use interfaces, some don't. Some implement own small services, some don't. Some use `http.get().map().subscribe()`, some just use `subscribe()`. I would really like to know how to do this properly and would be glad if somebody could enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

From my view the best practice is to use a service and use http get request to get json file from your server. We did the same for getting language json file.
If you want securely get json file then you should put your json file at secure folder rather than public folder and create an api to get json file or json object from server.

Hope it will help

Comment: In my case the json file is in the same directory as the  application, because it is rather small and not to be kept secret.

Comment: Another way is to create a constant object in any file and export that const object and import it in your component or service and use it. You don't need to do any extra task.